# my eclipse stopped working today

Tags: eclipse, macos, startup

Today I was running into problems with eclipse, like every time I closed a project a window popped up saying something like "error saving workspace" and complaining about apache xerces.

I decided to download a fresh install, and now it won't even start. I tried many variants (classic, javase, c++), hoping there was some distribution issues, but nothing worked. Eclipse starts saying "an error has occurred, see configurationlog ..."

Any idea? Are there some cached files in the system that might have become corrupted? I tried doing a "find / | grep eclipse" but found nothing interesting.

Thanks a lot for your help, I'm quite in trouble without it

Regards,

Nicola Montecchio

p.s. I tried also with 32 bit jvm but nothing changed

[edit] here is relevant bits of the log produced when starting:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-07-23 21:35:16.835
>   !MESSAGE An unexpected runtime error has occurred.
>   !STACK 0
>   javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-07-23 21:35:16.839
>   !MESSAGE 
>   !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAdaptorHook$ParsingService.getService()
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 0 2010-07-23 21:35:16.840
>   !MESSAGE Could not parse XML contribution for "org.eclipse.ant.core//plugin.xml". Any contributed extensions and extension points will be ignored.
>   !STACK 0
>   org.xml.sax.SAXException: Could not acquire XML parsing service.

and several other mostly related to xml ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your current workspace is severely broken.  Create a new workspace and import the projects from the old locations (File -> Import), and see if that helps.

Comment: the problem is eclipse does not start at all ... i only get the logo and the error box

Comment: Try moving the old workspace directory to a different name/location. Try adding "-clean" to `/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini`

Comment: See if there is anything in .eclipse in your home folder.  Then unzip Eclipse again, and start it, and specify an unused workspace location.  Does that help?

Comment: no, I removed everything I could, including .eclipse and workspace directory. thanks for your help anyway

Comment: If _that_ doesn't help, the problem may be elsewhere.  Can you run other Java programs?  Will NetBeans or Azureus run?

Comment: hi - netbeans runs perfectly, as do other java programs I coded! that's what's strange

Comment: Raise a bug with Eclipse.  If you hit a bug, it needs to
Be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Things I'd try are renaming your workspace (so Eclipse will use a fresh one when starting up) or running Eclipse with the -clean parameter (in the console with `./eclipse -clean` in your `eclipse/` folder).

Comment: @Nicola Another thing you could try is deleting `~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.eclipse.plist`