# problems with java installation (xerces) on mac

Tags: java, macos, installation, xerces

I'm using MacOsX 10.6.4.

Some time ago I run into problems with Eclipse (it wouldn't start anymore - I opened a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320918/my-eclipse-stopped-working-today) here and followed all the suggestion but with no luck).
Then I also run into very similar problems with other java applications, of which the last one is the android sdk. All these problems seem to be related with xerces/xml, as the following exception shows (just running tools/android and clicking on the "available updates" button):

> Exception in thread "Loading Source" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;

Is there any way to repair the java installation (reinstalling the OS is out of the question)?

thanks a lot

Nicola Montecchio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to try:

1. Look for adventitious `xerces` JARs that may have been inadvertently left in one of the directories of the `System` property `java.ext.dirs`.

   ```
   /Users/*/Library/Java/Extensions
   /Library/Java/Extensions
   /System/Library/Java/Extensions
   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/ext
   ```
2. Use spotlight to search for extraneous `xerces` JARs outside of Eclipse.
3. Remove `/Applications/eclipse` and `~/.eclipse`; reinstall Eclipse.
4. Reinstall Java from the the installer DVD: `/Volumes/Mac OS X Install DVD/Optional Installs/Xcode Tools/Packages/JavaSDK.pkg`.
5. Check [Software update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338).

Comment: FOUND!!! 
This was the problem: /Library/Java/Extensions/xerces.jar
After removing it, eclipse works!
I still have no Idea what was the cause though

Comment: Something must have put it there and that cannot be done without administrative rights.  What have you installed of OS X branded java related software since the machine was installed?

Comment: @Mark: Thanks; software update added. Looks like I'll have to tinker with the numbering. :-)

Comment: @Nicola Montecchio: `EclipseAdaptorHook`, was likely finding `xerces.jar in the `java.library.path` under `/Library/Java/Extensions/`.

Comment: @trashgod - 3 and 4 need swapping around (Actually could try 3 on its own and if that fails then 4)

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for looking at this. I had the nested list indented incorrectly, which caused the renumbering to restart. I think it's right now, but please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: oops renumbering seesm to have confused me - I meant Software update after java from the install DVD

Comment: @Mark: OK, that makes sense; one should run software update after installing from DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Trashgod,

Have a Huginn on me.

That not only solved my Eclipse/Android issue (Same as Nicola's) but also the failure of the Netbeans updater (Every version from 6.5 to 7.2) to work properly.

I found my little xerces bomb lurking in /User//Library/Java/Extensions and everything in there was from 2003/4 (Before I bought the Mac. Hmm...).
Anyhow, being a cautious type I just renamed the offender to xerces.jar.old.
That doesn't work.
Netbeans still had it open when I interrogated the task today.
So, I moved the entire Java folder to Previous_Java eh voila!

Machine behaves normally, java runs (7 from Oracle not 6.x from Apple and SDK), Android does stuff, Eclipse does stuff, Netbeans starts without bombing or going into a death spiral re-start loop.

A note for any Netbeans users with this problem... It can be amazingly frustrating trying to track it down.

regs

Tim