# Android SDK Manager Java "Loading Sources" Exception on OS X

Tags: java, android, xerces

I'm trying to get started with the Android SDK on OS X 10.6.8 but can't load any packages in the SDK manager.

Here's what I see in the SDK Manager: http://sarahtube.s3.amazonaws.com/20111221_Android_GUI_SDK_Manager_GUI_Java_Exception.jpg

Here's my Java/JDK:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

Here's the exception I get on loading the SDK or trying to update from within the SDK manager or from the command line:

> Exception in thread "Loading Sources" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.parseAddonsList(AddonsListFetcher.java:470)
>     at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetch(AddonsListFetcher.java:170)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.loadRemoteAddonsListInTask(UpdaterData.java:1042)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.access$900(UpdaterData.java:73)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData$5.run(UpdaterData.java:1012)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:128)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView.startTask(ProgressView.java:150)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressViewFactory.start(ProgressViewFactory.java:44)
>     at
>    com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.UpdaterData.loadRemoteAddonsList(UpdaterData.java:1010)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.sdkman2.PackageLoader$1.run(PackageLoader.java:169)
>     at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:118)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

I get this error with both R15 and R16 of the SDK. I previously installed R11 but that didn't work either so deleted that when R15 was released.

I have already set https URLs to be retrieved over http.

I'd really like to get into Android development so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Answering my own question as this might help others in the future.

After reading this answer [problems with java installation (xerces) on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432051/problems-with-java-installation-xerces-on-mac) I found an ancient xerces,jar in /Users/MYUSERDIR/Library/Java/Extensions/

Moving this out of the Extensions directory solved the issue.

Thanks stackoverflow (and me).