# Launching new version of a Java application opens old version

Tags: java, macos, swing, jvm

I have got a new version of a Java Swing Application (DMG file) that I want to test, but it keeps opening the Old version of the application, even though I have deleted the old application. It's like it's opening a cached version.

This is how I install the application:

- Open DMG file.
- Drag file to Application folder.

I only see this issue on OS X. On Windows it works fine.

I even tried running the jar file directly, and I see the same behaviour; it works on Windows but on Mac it shows the old version.

I tried the following but I saw the same behaviour:

- Restarting the computer
- Clearing/Deleting the Java cache (from
  `System Preference>Java>General>Temporary Internet Files>Settings>Delete Files...`)
- Logging as the Guest user on my mac.

Lastly, I have tried this on a different Mac and I do NOT see the issue. It seems like there is something specifically wrong with my OS X.

Comment: Right-click on the application and `Show Package Contents`; navigate to the `.jar`; inspect it; try running it directly.

Comment: @trashgod Did you mean something specific by 'inspect it'? I did click the Show Package Contents, and navigated to the .jar and ran it. Unfortunately, it still shows the old version. Which I find very strange!

Comment: _Is_ it the old version? Also, inspect the manifest, your execution `PATH`, the Java `CLASSPATH`, and [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3432254/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a copy of the old version in `/Users/*/Library/Java/Extensions` which was required by the Robot test automation framework.

Deleting it solved the issue.