# Eclipse fail at launching on Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Since I have downloaded a fresh install for my Eclipse, it can't start anymore. An error message says "An error has occurred See the log file /Applications/eclipse/configuration/1323191649568.log."

I have already deleted all the files and folders about Eclipse an Java Runtime several times before installing again. And, the command ./eclipse -clean give me the same error.

Any idea?

Here the log:

```
!SESSION 2011-12-07 01:27:30.742 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/Julien/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/Julien/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2011-12-07 01:27:31.721
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unknown repository type at file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.doCreateRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.createRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1005 2011-12-07 01:27:31.722
!MESSAGE Unknown repository type at file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2011-12-07 01:27:31.725
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create metadata repository for: file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create metadata repository for: file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-12-07 01:27:31.810
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. If you have details to add, edit the original question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have solved my problem by myself.

I "simply" re-installed Java. The manipulation is a bit tricky because Java is a part of OSX System and it not supposed to be uninstalled.

How to uninstall Java on OSX?

Download the last update from Apple website (Java for OS X Lion Update 1 - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1421)

1. Delete /Library/Java, /System/Library/Java, Library/Caches/Java folders
2. Open the Terminal with root (sudo -s)
3. Terminal: `pkgutil --packages | grep java`
4. Terminal: `pkgutil --forget com.apple.pkg.xxxxx` (everything about Java)
5. Insert the Mac OS X DVD
6. Terminal: `installer -verbose -pkg "/Volumes/Mac OS X Install DVD/System/Installation/Packages/Java.pkg" -target "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`
7. Terminal: `installer -verbose -pkg "/Volumes/Mac OS X Install DVD/System/Installation/Packages/JavaTools.pkg" -target "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`
8. Install the Java for OS X previously downloaded
9. Reboot
10. Software update if needed.

source: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2009051215025819

Comment: Good tip, one small correction: "java" should be capitalized in step 3, otherwise no packages may be found.

Answer (score 9):

Try deleting:
`/YOUR PATH TO WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources`

Answer (score 4):

try some of the suggestions here: [my eclipse stopped working today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320918/my-eclipse-stopped-working-today)

especially using terminal to run

> ./eclipse -clean

other potential solutions are these:

When downloading all the Eclipse/Java parts, be sure to save and unpack to an HFS+ partition. If you have, say, a FAT32 partition and save/unpack to there, that will cause installation problems (it happened to me).

Also, there may be issues with the 32-bit/64-bit installers.. be sure to pick the right one

Comment: worked like a charm for me. On OSX go to terminal and cd to $Eclipse_ Install_Location/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS and run eclipse -clean

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the entire metadata folder

> /YOUR PATH TO WORKSPACE/.metadata

Comment: Fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue. The eclipse was not loading in Mac system.

Referred solution provided in the link:
[Eclipse Kepler crashes in a certain workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999794/eclipse-kepler-crashes-in-a-certain-workspace)

As per suggestion, I deleted both:

1) eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources

2) .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

Now eclipse is loading without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the hidden file titled ".lock" from the workspace directory, that should do the trick.