# Eclipse "an error has occurred" at launch on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse fail at launching on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404295/eclipse-fail-at-launching-on-mac-osx)

Since I have downloaded a fresh install for my Eclipse, it can't start anymore. An error message says "An error has occurred See the log file /Applications/eclipse/configuration/1323191649568.log."

I have already deleted all the files and folders about Eclipse an Java Runtime several times before installing again. And, the command ./eclipse -clean give me the same error.

Any idea?

Here the log:

```
!SESSION 2011-12-07 01:27:30.742 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/Julien/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/Julien/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2011-12-07 01:27:31.721
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unknown repository type at file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.doCreateRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.createRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1005 2011-12-07 01:27:31.722
!MESSAGE Unknown repository type at file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2011-12-07 01:27:31.725
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create metadata repository for: file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create metadata repository for: file:/Applications/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/126/data/listener_1925729951/
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-12-07 01:27:31.810
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```