# Aptana (and eclipse) fail on start-up on mountain lion

Tags: eclipse, macos, aptana3

This may not be a mountain lion issue, but may be something simple; I'm trying to get to PyDev, installing Aptana Studio 3 as PyDev is included. Apologies for what might be a newb query, but I can't find any relevant breadcrumbs.

Installing on OSX 10.8.2, Java 1.6.0_35. Downloaded Aptana Studio 3.2.2, package installed fine. Starting the app fails with the attached trace, with either 32- or 64-bit jvms. Experimenting with Eclipse installed separately also fails with the same "unknown repository type" error.

The dir it's looking for does exist, and making it world-writable doesn't help.

Suggestions? Debugging tactics? Thanks in advance for any help.

Rick

---

```
!SESSION 2012-10-01 13:36:22.241 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_35
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/CS255/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/CS255/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2012-10-01 13:36:22.858
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unknown repository type at file:/Applications/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/194/data/listener_1925729951/.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.doCreateRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.createRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1005 2012-10-01 13:36:22.859
!MESSAGE Unknown repository type at file:/Applications/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/194/data/listener_1925729951/.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2012-10-01 13:36:22.870
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create metadata repository for: file:/Applications/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/194/data/listener_1925729951/
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create metadata repository for: file:/Applications/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/194/data/listener_1925729951/
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-01 13:36:23.014
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id has been found.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a file locking issue, but it's not straightforward, as changing permissions in obvious spots or moving the dist doesn't seem to fix it. The easiest workaround is to add

> -Dosgi.configuration.area=@user.home/.eclipse

to the eclipse.ini file, which gives each user (or just me) a writable config in their home dir.

Solution was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214957/locking-is-not-possible-in-the-directory-c-eclipse-configuration-org-eclipse-os).

Thanks to @irbull for his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with a read only directory trying to be updated.  While Eclipse 'should' support this, it doesn't appear to be. Can you try moving your Eclipse install to a different directory (say in your /Users//eclipse) instead of Applications.   It seems that MacOS doesn't allow Eclipse to write the configuration information to the /Applications folder.

Comment: No joy. I previously tried making the destination r/w, to no effect. Moving the eclipse directory to user space and making the entire tree world r/w didn't help. How does it tell the repository type? The directory is empty.

Comment: Hmm. This seems to be the same issue as reported at least twice, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409383/eclipse-an-error-has-occurred-at-launch-on-osx) and notably with a potential fix [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404295/eclipse-fail-at-launching-on-mac-osx). Sounds like it's time to reinstall Java. If anyone follows the crumbs to this comment, the Apple package for Java 1.6.0_35 on Mountain Lion is [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

Comment: Progress. Deinstalled and reinstalled java, had an interesting side conversation about unsetting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. Java works again, but eclipse still died with the same trace. Following up by running eclipse -clean seems to have fixed the issue. Fingers crossed. Thanks.