# Eclipse Kepler crashes in a certain workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, dropbox

I have a Dropbox workspace, and recently(this has never happened before), I came home(I edited some code at school also in the Dropbox workspace), and now Eclipse crashes everytime I use that workspace, but not any of my other workspaces. I have reinstalled Eclipse and tried to allocate from 512mb to 2gigs of RAM but nothing has happened. I've trimmed down the error code b/c it's over 52,000 characters long.

```
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-23 14:36:48.729
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-23 14:36:48.754
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Gannon'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-03-25 09:32:12.798 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-03-25 09:32:59.074
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon' from bundle '224'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-25 09:33:03.625
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-25 09:33:03.637
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\p0403472'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-03-26 09:45:15.868 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-03-26 09:45:23.311
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-03-26 09:45:24.866
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon' from bundle '224'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-26 09:45:28.804
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-26 09:45:28.815
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\p0403472'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-03-27 09:24:31.376 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-03-27 09:25:34.537
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-03-27 09:25:36.762
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon' from bundle '224'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-27 09:25:43.561
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-27 09:25:43.573
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\p0403472'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-03-28 09:15:05.491 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-03-28 09:19:51.740
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2014-03-28 09:19:54.051
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon' from bundle '224'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-28 09:20:01.572
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-03-28 09:20:01.583
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\p0403472'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-04-02 09:24:27.542 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [eclipse won't start but no error is shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847359/eclipse-wont-start-but-no-error-is-shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

- Try deleting the file `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap` or any .snap file under .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resource.

  You can do that using:

> $ cd eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources
>
> $ find . -type f -name "*.snap" | xargs rm

- Delete the .metadata directory from your workspace and restart
- Ensure that your workspace and projects have all the necessary permissions, try 777 for now.

Comment: deleting both .snap and.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi did the trick for me. Removing just .snap did not work. Eclipse Kepler.